# Identity Server4 Introspection Endpoint authentication with client credentials

Tags: identityserver4

I am a bit confused about the use case with reference tokens and the introspection endpoint in a MVC/Webforms scenario.

My basic question is why is the introspection endpoint only setup to allow authentication requests from ApiResource credentials, (api1/apisecret) and not allow for client credentials?  I am able to use the code bellow with ApiResource credentials, I just get unauthorized with client credentials.  I think this is as designed.

I want to give our systems admins the ability to revoke the tokens and force logout users.   My plan is to use the CookieAuthenticationProvider’s OnValidateIdentity to periodically validate the reference tokens and force a logout if needed.   I think that I can get similar functionality with short lived self-contained JWT tokens and refresh tokens but liked the simplicity of using reference tokens.   I can obviously use two sets of credentials in the same application, one for the client and one ApiResource, but is seams more intuitive to use/manage one set of credentials, the client’s.  Should I not use reference tokens for a server-side trusted application?

My clients are setup like the following.

```
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
```

Here are a few notes from my research.

Here are the docs about Introspection Endpoint - http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/introspection.html

Here is Dominick Baier's post about reference tokens - https://leastprivilege.com/2015/11/25/reference-tokens-and-introspection/

Here is an example of the IntrospectionClient call I am using. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Clients/src/ConsoleIntrospectionClient/Program.cs

Here is the spec for introspection and as you can see it does not indicate the type of authentication required.  - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662

> To prevent token scanning attacks, the endpoint MUST also require
> some form of authorization to access this endpoint, such as client
> authentication as described in OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749] or a separate
> OAuth 2.0 access token such as the bearer token described in OAuth
> 2.0 Bearer Token Usage [RFC6750].  The methods of managing and    validating these authentication credentials are out of scope of this
> specification.

This is a sample of a ApiResource with a secret.

```
           // simple version with ctor
            new ApiResource("api1", "Some API 1")
            {
                // this is needed for introspection when using reference tokens
                ApiSecrets = { new Secret("apisecret".Sha256()) }
            },
```

Here is the sample client form the ConsoleIntrospectionClient client.

```
    new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "roclient.reference",
                    ClientSecrets = 
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
    
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                    AllowedScopes = { "api1", "api2.read_only" },
    
                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference
                },
```